# Is there a way to get Strong Consistency with RocksDb in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency, rocksdb-java

I have a program which accesses a single RocksDB using multiple threads.

Our workflow for a given document is to read the cache, do some work, then update the cache.

My code uses chained CompletableFutures to process multiple documents in order (and processes the first document before starting the subsequent document). So my RocksDB workload consists of (read, write) repeated several times for the same key.

Most of the time we get the correct value from the cache for each run through the workflow, but occasionally we will get stale data. Each operation could run on one of many threads in the Executor, but they will never run in parallel for the same key.

Is there a way to ensure that we get strong **consistency**? I wrote a unit test to confirm that this happens, and it happens between 1-3% of the time. I even added a read-after-write, and that reduced the inconsistency, but did not eliminate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are referring to as strong consistency is rocksdb is strongly consistent - there is no across the network replication going on where you would see eventual consistency

if you want to get a snapshotted read use a snapshot sequence identifier when doing your reads

Sounds more like a threading issue where your reads and writes are happening in non-determenistic order

Comment: please see this question for more details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73723491/why-am-i-seeing-consistency-issues-with-rocksdb-java